# Google maps and JHipster

Tags: google-maps, jhipster

I am new to Jhipster and I have generated a monolithic application with angular on the client side and maven on the server side. My problem is that when I run maven, the map does not appear while when I only run angular, the map works fine.

For the map, I simply followed this link : https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/overview#maps_map_simple-html

Does anyone know what I need to add for this to work?
Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: Hi Nesrine! I'm glad you're using jhipster. Just to confirm a few details: you are running `./mvnw` in one tab, `npm start` in another tab, and then you navigate to the page where you expect to see the map and it is not there? I'd like to know more about what you mean by "only run angular."

Just a note: maven is a build tool that manages your server-side's dependencies, build, plugins, and many other components. It has a parallel in npm/node package manager. With your jhipster setup, you likely have a Java Spring Boot on your server and Angular for your client :)

Comment: Well, yes, not at the same time, of course. When I run ./mvnw, I get this  error in the inspector "ERROR ReferenceError: google is not defined", but when I run npm start, I can see the map without error.

Comment: Maybe webpack is stripping out your `<script>` contents when you run a prod build. Google search with right terms "google maps angular webpack"